# ¿Cómo borrar o editar mensajes antes enviados por un bot en telegram? PHP

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram.bot

Soy Joshi y estoy haciendo un bot en telegram para solucionarme algunas cosillas a la hora de contestar a mis clientes, para ello necesito que borre o edite un mensaje anteriormente enviado, un ejemplo sería este...

-Bot: Hola! Espera en lo que llega un asesor

- Llega el asesor *
- El bot edita el mensaje para ahora decir lo siguiente *

-Bot: Hola! Cual es tu problema? (editado)

Me leí la api de PHP Para los bots en telegram y no encuentro como obtener el ID De los mensajes enviados, solo de los recibidos

El código que encontré es el siguiente...

```
function Edit($chat_id, $msgID, $text){
    $url = $GLOBALS[website]."/editMessageText?chat_id=".$chat_id."&message_id=".$msgID."&text=".urlencode($text);
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Pero como ven se necesita la variable msgID, pero como les digo, a lo que yo sé solo se pueden obtener los ID´s de los mensajes recibidos!

Bonita tarde! :D

Comment: Solo capturalo así como capturas el userid